# How can I make the Div tag visible and invisible.?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two  tags d1 and d2(hidden), If I click on the textbox(t1) of d1 the d2 must get visible, and next if i click anywhere in the page except that  d2, the d2 must get hidden again and If i click of anywhere in the d2, the d2 must be visible only. d2 contans many child elements.

I have tried the code to make the d2 visible but i am not getting how to make it invisible again if we click outside the d2.

```
$("#t1").click(function () {
            $("#d2").removeClass("hidden");
});
```

I have two  tags d1 and d2(hidden), If I click on the textbox(t1) of d1 the d2 must get visible, and next if i click anywhere in the page except that textbox(t1) and d2, the d2 must get hidden again and If i click of anywhere in the d2, the d2 must be visible only.

Comment: please share the html code

Comment: Something that might be of interest to you: http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/

Comment: Please share the code snippet and screen shots if possible.

Comment: Share the html/css code please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this is what you are looking for,thanks

```js
$('#txt_Cartons1').click(function(e){      // click on text t1
         $('#hidden_div1').removeClass('hidden')
})

$(document).click(function(e){   // Click anywhere except t1 and d2
    if( !$(e.target).closest("#hidden_div1").length > 0 && ! $(e.target).closest("#txt_Cartons1").length > 0) {
         $('#hidden_div1').addClass('hidden')
    }
   
});
```

```css
.hidden
{
display:none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="row" id="outer_div"> // First Div d1 
<input type="text" id="txt_Cartons1" class="form-control value-control floating-label-control" data-isdynamic="false" data-placeholder="Cartons" data- label="Cartons" onfocus="SearchItems.init()" onblur="SearchItems.init()" /> 
</div> 

<div id="hidden_div1" class="hidden"> //Second Div d2 <Some Tags are there> </div>
```

Comment: I dont wanted to perform any action on d2 click, Means I wanted to keep it as its. Hope u got.

Comment: @TauFeeQ is this whatyou are expecting?

Comment: The code is sent by u is working fine in Stackoverflow compiler, I am changing the tags id as i am not dealing using the class name , I am using the Code to perform operation. Then its not working.

Comment: if you are using id then use $("#t2") instead of $('.t1')

Comment: "Bizgaze_SearchItems is not defined" means who have to decalre this fn first,check my snipet now

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#t1").click(function () {
  $("#d2").removeClass("hidden");
});

 $('body').on('click', function(a_event) {
   if (!$('#d2').is(a_event.target) && !$('#t1').is(a_event.target)) {
    $("#d2").addClass("hidden");
   }
 })
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution

On button click (t1), div (d2) is visible

```
$("#t1").on("click",function () {
        $("#d2").css("display","block");   
 });
```

On page click d2 need to be hide

```
$('body').on('click', function() {   
     $("#d2").css("display","none");
 });
```

Comment: Shivani actually there are two div, d1 and d2(invisible), If u click on textbox(t1) of d1, the d2 should get visible, And if u click on anywhere on visibled d2 no need to do anything coz there are textboxes in d2 we have fill the values in it, and as now d2 is visible and if u click outside the d2 except t1, the d2 should get hide again. Hope u got the requirements.